# How to make Tint2 open system tray apps on the current workspace in Openbox?

Tags: openbox, tint2

I'm using Openbox as my window manager on Debian, and I'm facing an issue with system tray icons. When I click on a system tray icon for an application, it doesn't bring the application to the current workspace; instead, it remains on the workspace where it was originally opened.

This behavior occurs with various applications and it's causing some inconvenience in my workflow.

Is there a way to configure Tint2 or Openbox to make applications open on the current workspace when I click their system tray icons?

---

This behavior is also observed when using keybindings to open applications that are already running on other workspaces. When I use their keybindings to open them because they are already open on another workspace, nothing changes in terms of their workspace location.

To address this, I've created a script that first checks if a program is already running, and if it is, it moves it to the current workspace; if not, it opens it. However, I'm unsure how to handle the system tray issue.